# Scraping data from span tag with class using BS

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to scrape project's names from Gitlab. When I inspect source code I see that name of project is in:

```
<span class='project-name'>Project Name</span>
```

Unfortunately, when I try to scrape this date I got empty list, My code looks like:

```
url = 'https://gitlab.com/users/USER/projects'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
repos = [repo.text for repo in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'project-name'})]
```

I was trying other solutions like using `attrs`, `class_` or using other HTML tags, but nothing works. What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like when you inspect the page in the network tabs in chrome developer tools, you can see that projects are not rendered when request is made:

[image]

What that means is, project information is requested after. In order to get the projects you need to send a request to `https://gitlab.com/users/USER/projects.json` endpoint:

[image]

After that you can inspect the response from that endpoint. As you can see the response here is json so we can load json data with `json` module and then in that dictionary there is an entry called `html` which has html data in it, so we can parse it with beautifulsoup and the rest of the code stays the same:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import urllib, json
url = 'https://gitlab.com/users/USER/projects.json'
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(json.loads(source)["html"],'html.parser')
repos = [repo.text for repo in soup.find_all('span',{'class':'project-name'})]
print(repos)
```

**Output:**

```
['freebsd', 'freebsd-ports', 'freebsd-test', 'risc-vhdl', 'dotfiles', 'tideyBot']
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work for me. I tried with loop for every project and with just single. I see you have changed endpoint to /user/repo instead of users/USER/projects.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay attention to what you said, now the answer should explain you what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, works as should. I suppose, that BitBucket has the same problem, because I have similiar problem there

Comment: Probably yes, most websites use internal APIs to get data faster or to reduce the load time.

Comment: Yeah, I still have problem with BitBucket - https://bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT/commits/ - Im trying to scrape data from this endpoint and tried using your solution like inspect network etc, but I didnt find anything. Would you like to have a look there?

Comment: [Here](https://i.imgur.com/mhMbtWR.png) is what you are looking for I think :). If you have any problems about understanding the data, I suggest you to use json beautifiers to have better understanding about the structure of json data. Like [this one](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer).

Comment: Wow, it looks crazy to scrape from there